# remove duplication in try and except block

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have duplications in try and except block. How can I remove the duplication from my code?

```
def ssh_function():
for test in xyz:
    try:
        device = ConnectHandler(ip=test, 
                                username='admin', 
                                password='admin', 
                                device_type='cisco_ios')
        print(device.find_prompt())
        print(device.send_command('wr mem'))

    except Exception:
        device = ConnectHandler(ip=test, 
                                username='admin', 
                                password='admin', 
                                device_type='cisco_ios_telnet')  #### Different from try block
        print(device.find_prompt())
        print(device.send_command('wr mem'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the repeated code out of the try-except clauses:

```
try:
    device = ...
except:
    device = ...

print(device.find_prompt())
print(device.send_command('wr mem'))
print('#' * 80, '\n')
```